# Error when trying to authenticate Spotify: Bad Request Error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, spotipy

I was trying to run the following code on my jupyter notebook:

```
import spotipy 
sp = spotipy.Spotify() 
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials 
import spotipy.util as util

# setting up authorization
cid ="my client id" 
secret = "my client secret"
# saving the info you're going to need
username = 'your_account_number'
scope = 'user-library-read' #check the documentation
authorization_url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize'
token_url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token'
redirect_uri ='https://localhost.com/callback/'

token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username,scope,client_id='client_id_number',client_secret='client_secret',redirect_uri='https://localhost.com/callback/')
client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=cid, client_secret=secret)
sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)
```

Which would redirect me to a site. However the site just contains a text saying "INVALID_CLIENT: Invalid client" and nothing else. When I paste this URL in the prompt, I keep getting a Bad Request error. I would be grateful for any help or guidance you can provide. Thanks!

Comment: To obtain a client id and client secret, you have to create an application through https://developer.spotify.com/dashboard/ . Did you do that?

Comment: @Chris Yes, I've got the both the ID and the secret.

Answer (score 0):

this was the code that worked for me:

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
import spotipy.util as util
import os
from Spotify_isplaying import isplay

os.environ["SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID"] = '' # client id
os.environ["SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET"] = '' # Secret ID
os.environ["SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI"] = '' # Redirect URI
username = "" # username
client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id="SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID",client_secret="SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET")
sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)
scope = '' # scope needed for your programme 
token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope)
if token:
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
else:
    print("Can't get token for", username)
# where you put your code
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/late-answers/26237679)